# What is the solution to this recursion?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Take $a_0=10^6$.

What is $a_n$ (asymptotically) where $a_{i+1}=a_i+\sqrt[\alpha]{a_i}$ where $\alpha>1$?

How fast does $a_n$ grow?

Comment: $a_n/n^2\to 1/4$, see my answer to essentially the same question here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485482/a-limit-about-a-1-1-a-n1-a-n-sqrta-n/1485494#1485494

Comment: That's for the square root; here we'll have something like $a_n\sim n^\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}$

Comment: @IvanNeretin can you show this below?

Comment: Well, the main idea is the same as in Christian's answer to the other question, and the rest is just too boring.